# Trim Trailing 0 from one colum in query Select *

Tags: mysql

If in `SELECT` query name each column and for one column use `TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM ColumnName) AS ColumnName` then ok.

But what if `SELECT *` and want to use `Trim Trailing 0` for one column?

To use something like `SELECT *, REPLACE(ColumnName, '0', '')`? But need to replace only ending `0`

Comment: It's not advisable to use `SELECT *` anyway. [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: OK. `SELECT *` is bad. What is alternative? Simply name each necessary column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT data.*,
       TRIM(TRAILING '0' from ExchangeRate) AS ExchangeRateTrimmed
FROM (.
  ... the subquery ...
) data
```

Hovever, this query returs all columns from the subquery (including `ExchangeRate` column) plus a new, additional column - `ExchangeRateTrimmed`.

Unfortunately ANSI SQL standard doesn't have a shotrtcut using '*' with the semantic "give me all columns, but modify only one of them" nor "give me all columns except one".

For now `SELECT *` means "give me all columns - as they are in the table (or subquery), without the ability to change them".

If you want to change one column using an expression, then you must list all of the others columns in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       .....
       expression on col X [as col_name],
       ....
       colN
FROM table
```

Comment: Yes, I listed all necessary columns (taking into account that `SELECT *` is not good option).

Answer (score 0):

`select *.TRIM(TRAILING '0' from ColumnName) AS ColumnName`

Comment: Did you try this somewhere? I can't find this kind of syntax anywhere.

Comment: @Meabed is this a comment for me or mostafa?

Comment: Unfortunately can not get it to work. Initial query was `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate FROM 2_1_journal) DATA ` Changed to `SELECT *.TRIM(TRAILING '0' from ExchangeRate) AS ExchangeRate FROM ( SELECT * , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate FROM 2_1_journal) DATA ` And no result, no errors.